# Changing the color of font with a click

Tags: c++, api, winapi

I'm using win32 API and this is my code(I've already had a little help from this site ;) ).

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND hwnd, UINT message, 
                          WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
     {
     HDC  hdc;
     PAINTSTRUCT ps;
     RECT        rect;
     RECT        size;
     int         width;
     char *     widthHeight;
     static char        Swidth[32];
     static char        Sheight[32];
     int         height;
     char       sBottom[32];
     char       sTop[32];
     char       sLeft[32];
     char       sRight[32];
     char       SrightButtonClicked[32];
     static int rightButtonClicked = 0;
     char       SleftButtonClicked[32];
     static int leftButtonClicked = 0;
     static bool LeftButtonClicked = false;
     static bool RightButtonClicked = false;

     switch (message)
         {
          case WM_PAINT:
                hdc = BeginPaint (hwnd, &ps);

                if(LeftButtonClicked == true)
                {
                    SetDCPenColor(hdc, RGB(0, 0, 255));
                    LeftButtonClicked = false;
                }

                if(RightButtonClicked == true)
                {
                    SetDCPenColor(hdc, RGB(255, 0, 0));
                    RightButtonClicked = false;
                }

                GetClientRect (hwnd, &rect);

                GetWindowRect(hwnd, &size);

                //Variables used in outputting.
                width = size.right - size.left;
                itoa(width, Swidth, 10);
                height = size.bottom - size.top;
                itoa(height, Sheight, 10);
                itoa(rect.bottom, sBottom, 10);
                itoa(rect.top, sTop, 10);
                itoa(rect.left, sLeft, 10);
                itoa(rect.right, sRight, 10);

                //Line 1, Width and height output
                TextOut(hdc, 0, 0, "Here is my width: ", 18);
                TextOut(hdc, 125, 0, Swidth, 5);
                TextOut(hdc, 175, 0, "Here is my height: ", 18);
                TextOut(hdc, 300, 0, Sheight, 4);

                //Line 2, Output the bottom, right, left, and top of the window
                TextOut(hdc, 0, 20, sBottom, strlen(sBottom));
                TextOut(hdc, 50, 20, sTop, strlen(sTop));
                TextOut(hdc, 100, 20, sRight, strlen(sRight));
                TextOut(hdc, 150, 20, sLeft, strlen(sLeft));

                //Outputs the number of times right click has been clicked
                TextOut(hdc, 0, 40, "Right Button Clicked: ", 23);
                itoa(rightButtonClicked, SrightButtonClicked, 10);
                TextOut(hdc, 150, 40, SrightButtonClicked, strlen(SrightButtonClicked));

                //Output the number of times left click has been clicked
                TextOut(hdc, 0, 60, "Left Button Clicked: ", 22);
                itoa(leftButtonClicked, SleftButtonClicked, 10);
                TextOut(hdc, 150, 60, SleftButtonClicked, strlen(SleftButtonClicked));
                EndPaint (hwnd, &ps);
                return 0;

          case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:

              leftButtonClicked++;
              LeftButtonClicked = true;
              InvalidateRect(hwnd, 0, true);
              return 0;

          case WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
              rightButtonClicked++;
              RightButtonClicked = true;

              //Uses char * widthHeight to concat all the resolution into one char to output in Messagebox
              widthHeight = new char[strlen(Swidth) + strlen(Sheight) + 4];
              widthHeight = Swidth;
              strcat(widthHeight, " x ");
              strcat(widthHeight, Sheight);

              //Has a message box pop up with resolution of window in Mouse Button OK format
              MessageBox(NULL, widthHeight , "Right Mouse Button Pressed!", MB_OK);
              InvalidateRect(hwnd, 0, true);
              return 0;

          case WM_DESTROY:
              PostQuitMessage(0);
              return 0;

         }

     return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
     }
```

Now I want to make it do something like change the text color when I left click to a color.. Say red? and when I right click have it go to blue.. How would I go about doing this? I've googled it a lot and everything just seems very complicated.

Comment: Please read the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145133(v=vs.85).aspx) for TextOut, it shows you what colors it uses to render the text.  Links to the winapi functions that change these colors are at the bottom of the article.  Petzold's Programming Windows is also an excellent source of basic information like this.

Comment: Thank you =). That worked. I didn't realize it was that simple!

Answer (score 0):

Try this before you begin output (after your BeginPaint() call will work):

```
// Set the Pen to Blue
SetDCPenColor(hdc, RGB(0,0,255));
```

To do what you are wanting just set a value in your mouse down handler that you check for in your paint handler. Use black if it's not set [ RGB(0,0,0) ] and if it is set use blue [ RGB(0,0,255) ].

EDIT: Also DON'T use static hdc. Everyone wants to do that but it doesn't work. HDC is actually maintained out of process by the OS and therefore C++ will not be able to keep track of it. This is a guaranteed failure eventually. Always get a fresh hdc (or anything named DC for that matter) before using it.

EDIT 2: Try this instead...

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND hwnd, UINT message, 
                      WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
 {
 HDC  hdc;
 PAINTSTRUCT ps;
 RECT        rect;
 RECT        size;
 int         width;
 char *     widthHeight;
 static char        Swidth[32];
 static char        Sheight[32];
 int         height;
 char       sBottom[32];
 char       sTop[32];
 char       sLeft[32];
 char       sRight[32];
 char       SrightButtonClicked[32];
 static int rightButtonClicked = 0;
 char       SleftButtonClicked[32];
 static int leftButtonClicked = 0;
 static bool LeftButtonClicked = false;
 static bool RightButtonClicked = false;
 static COLORREF pencolor = RGB(0,0,0); // Added by KRowe

 switch (message)
     {
      case WM_PAINT:
            hdc = BeginPaint (hwnd, &ps);

            SetDCPenColor(hdc, pencolor); // Added by KRowe

            GetClientRect (hwnd, &rect);
            GetWindowRect(hwnd, &size);

            //Variables used in outputting.
            width = size.right - size.left;
            itoa(width, Swidth, 10);
            height = size.bottom - size.top;
            itoa(height, Sheight, 10);
            itoa(rect.bottom, sBottom, 10);
            itoa(rect.top, sTop, 10);
            itoa(rect.left, sLeft, 10);
            itoa(rect.right, sRight, 10);

            //Line 1, Width and height output
            TextOut(hdc, 0, 0, "Here is my width: ", 18);
            TextOut(hdc, 125, 0, Swidth, 5);
            TextOut(hdc, 175, 0, "Here is my height: ", 18);
            TextOut(hdc, 300, 0, Sheight, 4);

            //Line 2, Output the bottom, right, left, and top of the window
            TextOut(hdc, 0, 20, sBottom, strlen(sBottom));
            TextOut(hdc, 50, 20, sTop, strlen(sTop));
            TextOut(hdc, 100, 20, sRight, strlen(sRight));
            TextOut(hdc, 150, 20, sLeft, strlen(sLeft));

            //Outputs the number of times right click has been clicked
            TextOut(hdc, 0, 40, "Right Button Clicked: ", 23);
            itoa(rightButtonClicked, SrightButtonClicked, 10);
            TextOut(hdc, 150, 40, SrightButtonClicked, strlen(SrightButtonClicked));

            //Output the number of times left click has been clicked
            TextOut(hdc, 0, 60, "Left Button Clicked: ", 22);
            itoa(leftButtonClicked, SleftButtonClicked, 10);
            TextOut(hdc, 150, 60, SleftButtonClicked, strlen(SleftButtonClicked));
            EndPaint (hwnd, &ps);
            return 0;

      case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:

          leftButtonClicked++;
          LeftButtonClicked = true;
          pencolor = RGB(255,0,0); // Added by KRowe
          InvalidateRect(hwnd, 0, true);
          return 0;

      case WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
          rightButtonClicked++;
          RightButtonClicked = true;
          pencolor = RGB(0, 255,0); // Added by KRowe
          widthHeight = new char[strlen(Swidth) + strlen(Sheight) + 4];
          widthHeight = Swidth;
          strcat(widthHeight, " x ");
          strcat(widthHeight, Sheight);

          //Has a message box pop up with resolution of window in Mouse Button OK format
          MessageBox(NULL, widthHeight , "Right Mouse Button Pressed!", MB_OK);
          InvalidateRect(hwnd, 0, true);
          return 0;

      case WM_DESTROY:
          PostQuitMessage(0);
          return 0;

     }

 return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
 }
```

Comment: No luck. I had to make my hdc variable static to make it not break but it still doesn't turn the text blue.

Comment: Correct me if i'm mistaken but I thought  hdc can only be used by setting it equal to BeginPaint and Begin and End paint are only used in WM_PAINT.. So How would I get a new hdc in my case statement?? Just make a BeginPaint and EndPaint in there?

Comment: I edited my previous post to include my new code that doesn't work.. :(